# Minimum size of the generating set of a direct product of symmetric groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. Let $S_m$ and $S_n$ be the symmetric groups on the sets $\{1,\dots,m\}$ and $\{1,\dots,n\}$, respectively. What is the minimum size of a generating set for the direct product $S_m\times S_n$?

Comment: Do you have an example where it is not the sum of the size of the generatosfor $S_m$ and $S_n$ ?

Comment: yes I have the example where size of generators less than the sum of S_m and S_n.

Comment: why don't you put that example to your question ?

Comment: because I want to know different ideas from everyone. I claim that we can use only 2 elements for generate S_m X S_n.

Comment: Hmm. If a set generates $G\times H$, its projections generate $G$ resp. $H$. That makes the claim that two elements suffice quite dubious.

Comment: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Minimum_size_of_generating_set_of_direct_product_of_two_groups_may_be_strictly_less_than_sum_of_minimum_size_of_generating_set_of_each_factor

Comment: @Daniel: If $m$ and $n$ are both odd, then it is clear that the permutations $\alpha=(123\ldots m)(1'2')$ and
$\beta=(12)(1'2'3'\ldots n')$ generate the whole thing, because $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^n$ generate $S_m$ and $\alpha^m$ and $\beta^2$ generate $S_n$. Here I have $S_n$ acting on primed numbers $1',2',\ldots$.

Comment: the above link is the example of the minimum size of S_3 X S_3.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes. But for even $m,\,n$ I don't see anything like that. I may have misunderstood the comment, and the OP meant for some $m,\,n$, and not "for all".

Answer (score 5):

Let $S_m$ act on $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ and $S_n$ on $\{1',2',\ldots,n'\}.$

[adding more detail to the following paragraph as per request]
A fact given in most elementary texts on permutation groups is that the 2-cycles
$(12),(13),(14),\ldots,(1m)$ generate all of $S_m$.
With that result known we next see that two generators $\sigma=(12)$ and $\tau=(123\cdots m)$ generate all of $S_m$. This is because we get sufficiently many transpositions by conjugating the former by powers of the latter. For example $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=(23)$, $\tau^2\sigma\tau^{-2}=(34)$
et cetera. Further conjugating gives $(13)=(23)(12)(23)$ and so forth.
Similarly we can use $\tau'=(23\cdots m)$ in place of $\tau$: $\tau'^k\sigma\tau'^{-k}$ gives the 2-cycles $(1j), 1<j\le m$, and having these suffices.

I think that two generators will always suffice to generate the direct product.

If $m$ and $n$ are both odd, then it is clear that the permutations $\alpha=(123\ldots m)(1'2')$ and
$\beta=(12)(1'2'3'\ldots n')$ generate the whole thing, because $\alpha^2$ and $\beta^n$ generate $S_m$ and $\alpha^m$ and $\beta^2$ generate $S_n$. The general observation here is that if a permutation $\sigma$ is the product of two
disjoint cycles of coprime lengths, then the individual cycles belong to the subgroup generated by $\sigma$.

If either $m$ (resp. $n$) is even, then we use $(23\ldots m)(1'2')$ (resp.
$(12)(2'3'\cdots n')$) instead as the other generator. The key is that the longer
cycle is of an odd length, so the above observation applies.

Addedum: A single generator obviously won't do :-)

Comment: Can you explain more ? If I pick (a,b) in S_m X S_n, then (a,b)=...(What is the product of (a,b) in term of the alpha and beta).

Comment: @sommanee.w: I added more details. There is no short answer to your question. But an algorithm for producing those can be described. To do that you have to first write both $a$ and $b$ as products of 2-cycles. Then do a bit of conjugating to replace those 2-cycles with other 2-cycles that you know how to write in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Now I'm having some doubts. I wouldn't be at all surprised, if, say, Derek Holt had already handled this question earlier. I couldn't find it, but my search skills are not very good.

Comment: Your answer seems fine to me (assuming $m,n \geq 2$). It was fine 2 days ago too, but my teaching duties keep me too busy to read answers daily. :-)

Comment: Thanks, @Jack.  Sorry about the repeated bumps. I was trying to make it clearer to the OP, but haven't heard from them since the day of the question.