# Generators of a direct product of symmetric groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product

This question is a generalization of [Minimum size of the generating set of a direct product of symmetric groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486562/minimum-size-of-the-generating-set-of-a-direct-product-of-symmetric-groups) to a product of arbitrary arity, and the only answer to that question is incomplete (it doesn't talk about $S_m \times S_n$ with both $m$ and $n$ even).

So, the question is: how can one build a minimal set of generators for the direct product $S_{n_1} \times S_{n_2} \times \ldots \times S_{n_k}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q.** *how can one build a minimal set of generators for the direct product
$S_{n_1}\times \cdots \times S_{n_k}$?*

I will interpret *minimal* to mean *minimal size*.

First, there is a unique minimal size set of generators for $S_2$, and it is
$\{(1\;2)\}$. It has size $1$.

For $n>2$, a minimal size set of generators for $S_n$ has size $2$,
and $\{(1\;2), (1\;2\;\cdots\;n)\}$ is one such. Another $2$-element generating set is $\{(1\;2), (2\;3\;\cdots\;n)\}$.

There is nothing more that needs to be said about the case
where the number of factors, $k$, is $1$.

I claim that, when $k>1$ and all factors are nontrivial,
a minimal size set of generators for
$S_{n_1}\times \cdots \times S_{n_k}$ has size $k$.

**$k$ is a lower bound.**
$(S_{n_1}\times \cdots \times S_{n_k})/
(A_{n_1}\times \cdots \times A_{n_k})\cong \mathbb Z_2^k$,
which is a vector space over the $2$-element field.
This quotient requires $k$ generators,
because it is $k$-dimensional, so the original group
$S_{n_1}\times \cdots \times S_{n_k}$
requires at least $k$ generators.

**An explicit generating set with no more than $k$ elements.**
I will follow the idea of
[Minimum size of the generating set of a direct product of symmetric groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486562/minimum-size-of-the-generating-set-of-a-direct-product-of-symmetric-groups), where this problem is solved for the case $k=2$.

I assume that $S_{n_i}$ acts on the set
$X^{(i)} = \{1^{(i)},\ldots,n_i^{(i)}\}$,
and that the sets $X^{(i)}$, $1\leq i\leq k$,  are pairwise disjoint.
$S_{n_1}\times \cdots \times S_{n_k}$ acts on $X^{(1)}\cup\cdots\cup X^{(k)}$.
Define $\tau_i = (1^{(i)}\;2^{(i)})$ and
$$
\sigma_i = \begin{cases}
(1^{(i)}\;2^{(i)}\;\cdots\;n_i^{(i)})& \textrm{if $n_i$ is odd,}\\
(2^{(i)}\;3^{(i)}\;\cdots\;n_i^{(i)})& \textrm{if $n_i$ is even.}
\end{cases}
$$
Here if $n_i$ is odd, then the cycle $\sigma_i$ has odd length $n_i$,
while if $n_i$ is even, then $\sigma_i$ has odd length $n_i-1$.
Whatever the parity of $n_i$, the cycle $\sigma_i$ has odd length.

Everybody knows that $S_{n_i}$ is generated by $\{\tau_i, \sigma_i\}$.

A $k$-element
generating set for $S_{n_1}\times \cdots \times S_{n_k}$ is
$$
G:=\{\tau_1\cdot\sigma_2, \tau_2\cdot\sigma_3,\ldots, \tau_k\cdot\sigma_1\}.
$$
If $\alpha = \tau_i\cdot\sigma_{i+1}$, then
$\alpha^{|\sigma_{i+1}|} = \tau_i$ and $\alpha^{|\sigma_{i+1}|+1} = \sigma_{i+1}$,
so any subgroup containing $\tau_i\cdot\sigma_{i+1}$ contains both
$\tau_i$ and $\sigma_{i+1}$. Hence the subgroup generated
by $G$ contains $\{\tau_i,\sigma_i\}$ for all $i$, and therefore
is the full product.

Comment: The generating set is perfect, but I'm not convinced by the lower bound proof (although I'm sure it's the correct bound), in particular by the quotient generators size forcing the full group one