# The structure of the group $S_2×S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that the group $S_2$×$S_3$ is generated by two elements

I am able to prove that elements a and b can generate at least a subgroup of order 6, but I am not able to prove that they can generate the entire group

Comment: Well, what is the order of $\;S_2\times S_3\;$ ? There you go...

Comment: @DonAntonio Its 12, but what does it give me?

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948054/generators-of-a-direct-product-of-symmetric-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1) proves that products of $k$ symmetric groups have $k$ generators. Take $k=2$ here.

Comment: So $S_m\times S_n$ for $n,m\ge 2$ can be generated by $2$ elements. A proof for this is also given at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486562/minimum-size-of-the-generating-set-of-a-direct-product-of-symmetric-groups), by Jyrki.